# Need algorithm for choosing sets of integer from list of such sets

Tags: algorithm

I have a list whose members are sets of 5 numbers chosen from the
integers 1 to 600 [or 0 to 599 for storage purposes].
I need to choose a sublist of this list such that among the sets in this
sublist, each integer in the 1 to 600 range appears exactly once, so a
sublist of 120 elements.  My list has either 4200 or 840 elements in
it--I'll find out by running whether the bigger number is necessary.
I need any one such sublist.

This sounds like a standard problem to me, but I have no idea how to
search. Can someone help with providing an algorithm, please?

Comment: [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Answer (score 1):

From [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

> The greedy algorithm for set covering chooses sets according to one rule: at each stage, choose the set that contains the largest number of uncovered elements

Wikipedia seems to say that this algorithm works the best under plausible complexity assumptions.

I would boil it down to these steps:

1. Pick an element from the list (the first one, probably)
2. Pick the next element you come across where all 5 numbers are not yet represented in the sub-list
3. If you reach the end, go back to the beginning of the list and lower the criteria of step #2 to 4 numbers
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3 until you have covered all integers

Depending on the programming language you're using, there are ways of making this pretty quick.

**Edit: the poster has explained that each integer must be used *exactly* once**

So, what you really need to do is just continue adding elements until the element contains an integer that is already present in your subset. The "exactly" criterion takes precedent over the "not yet in the subset" criterion. You'll break out of the loop when you hit 120 subsets.

You may also want to keep track of the order in which you add elements to your subset, and when you hit a dead end (e.g., each of the elements remaining in the superset contains an integer that is already present in your subset) you backtrack one element and continue.

In order to backtrack and remember what combinations do not work, you will need to keep a list of "banned collections", and each time you decide whether to add a new element you should first make sure it's not in this list of banned collections. The best way (that I've found) to do this in Ruby is to store the Hash of the collection rather than the collection itself. This provides an inexpensive way to evaluate whether the prospective collection has already been tried and has led to a dead-end.

Good luck!

Comment: Just thinking -- you may want to revise step #2 to "skip elements while the element contains a number that is already represented in the sublist," as this may be more efficient.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding you. As soon as I go to step 2, it seems to me, I begin to accept sets containing an element that's already been covered: I need to cover the 600 in such a way that no integer in the range is used more than once. I think that if I begin in the fashion above, I'll need a way to remove sets as well as just accumulating them.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, that's more difficult, because there's the possibility that a solution does not exist – but you would have to exhaust all possible combinations to find that out.

Comment: Thank you, @acsmith. When I look at my failed attempt (in Python, whose data structures and sets really are doing a lot of the work for me), I see that I've essentially tried your step 1 without any backtracking.  I'll now try to see whether I can tame backtracking enough not to get me thoroughly lost here. I do need your 'good luck'!